# Google Deep links error: "Your app's back button doesn't send users back to search results"

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have an Android app, and also a website that show the same content.
I setup google deep linking, placing a meta field on each page with the url that matches that content in my android app.

Google is crawling my app and sends me an email stating that "Your app's back button doesn't send users back to search results"

I get instructions to check the app links using applinktest.appspot.com/....

When I do so, if my app is not on the background on the testing device, then the back button works OK, going back to Chrome and the app links test page.

If the app is in the background, then the back button does not go back to the test page, but to the previous activity in the stack. What I'm interpreting is that the activity launched from the link is placed on top of the stack the app in the background had, and as this stack is not empty, then the back doesn't return to the test page but to the previous activity in the stack (still in my app).

I would think the crawler would always launch my app from scratch, and would not find this problem scenario, should I even try to fix it? Maybe the problem the crawler is having is something else... if not I think this would happen to most people implementing google deep linking, but so far I cannot find people complaining about the same scenario.

Anyone having the same problem reported by Google? How did you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I clear my app's navigation stack to resolve this. But when I press the back button, it does not go to search results page. Instead everything shuts down (App and google chrome). Now when I click on Google Chrome, search results page is up. @Maria Del Valle Duhagon do you face this issue too?

Comment: I did not try to clear my app's navigation stack. After handling the first scenario well (back button takes you to the results if app wasn't on background) google stopped complaining about the issue. Other issues arose, but not that one, so we left it as it was.